# How do get data from example owl data using sparql query

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, ontology, fuseki

This is my example owl :

```
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#Person"/>
    <foaf:age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">10</foaf:age>
    <foaf:birthday rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">10.10</foaf:birthday>
    <foaf:firstName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Liis</foaf:firstName>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

And because im rookie with sparql, i want to know how do make a query to get all instances with this rdf a
`<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#Person"/>`

nd then get the data from it example like get age and the get age=10 or get name and name="someName"
`<foaf:age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">10</foaf:age>` i mean get data from this row.

Comment: and you did not read any SPARQL tutorial I guess?

Comment: SPARQL = query language for RDF. You can serialize OWL data as RDF triples. Ideally, you look at your data in N-Triples or even better Turtle syntax. SPARQL syntax is close to it.

Comment: I'll give you an entry point, the rest is your task, because you have to learn it by yourself: `select ?s where {?s rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#Person>}` - this will return all persons (don't forget to add the prefix declaration for `rdf` or just use `a` instead of `rdf:type`)

Comment: I read SPARQL tutorial, but i didnt get it right away, ohh tnx m8, that resolved my problem :)

Comment: once you got the full query working, don't forget to post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

My answares to this question are: 
This query help you to find all instances, s is the object name, p is the type how do accsess to this data and o is the value of the row.

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX resource: <http://purl.org/vocab/resourcelist/schema#>

select distinct ?s ?p ?o ?k where {
?s ?p ?o ;
  a <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#Person> .
?k foaf:age ?x .}
```

and the second part `?k foaf:age ?x .` is how do accsess to instance data by the type name.
and the result is `<http://example.register.nl/nationaalhandelsregister#person1>,10`